# (Symfony 4) How can I get the base URI of my project (the http://www.yourwebsite.com/) from within a non-controller class?

Tags: symfony, uri, radix

How can I get the "http://www.yourwebsite.com" from my repository class in Symfony 4?

The reason why I need to do this is because I'm using the Liip image service which returns the entire url, and I only need the url relative to the root, so I have to strip out the "http://www.yourwebsite.com" from the path returned.

I have used KernelInterface and that only returns the path from within your machine (i.e. the var/www/... in your machine).

I've tried injecting http foundation's Request object so I can call the getPathInfo() method, here is what I have in my repository class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PhotoRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{ 
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }
```

But I just get the error `Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\PhotoRepository": argument "$request" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" but no such service exists.`

Here is what I have under "services" in my services.yaml:

```
App\Repository\PhotoRepository:
    arguments:
        - Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
```

Here is the full path to my file generated:

```
"http://www.mywebsite.com/media/cache/my_thumb/tmp/phpNbEjUt"
```

I need to parse out the get the `http://www.mywebsite.com` and just get the `/media/cache/my_thumb/tmp/phpNbEjUt` from the path.

Comment: The [RequestStack](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) will get you pass the immediate problem.  Only pull the request when you need it.  Not in the constructor.  I'm a bit dubious that you actually need the base url but I admit I have not used the image bundle.

Comment: Hi Cerad, if I pass it to the actual function I get "Too few arguments to function App\Repository\PhotoRepository::addPhoto(), 3 passed in /var/www/vhosts/kinkrebel.com/src/Repository/PhotoRepository.php on line 181 and exactly 4 expected" and if I set it in my constructor I get "Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\PhotoRepository": argument "$request" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" but no such service exists" so it looks like I can't use Request at all.

Comment: The real problem is that you don't quite understand how the ServiceEntityRepository constructor works.  I don't really have the interest at this point to gin up a working example.  But do some searching on how to inject additional arguments to a service repository.

Comment: Ok will do Cerad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cerad already wrote in the comments, you can inject the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack`:

```
App\Repository\PhotoRepository:
    arguments:
        - Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
        - Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry
```

Your constructor for the PhotoRepository will then look something like:

```
class PhotoRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{ 
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        parent::__construct($managerRegistry, Photo::class);

        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can then determine the current URL using something like this:

```
private function getCurrentUrl(): string
{
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

    return $request->getBaseUrl(); // or possibly getUri()
}
```